# Как пропустить массив в запрос MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть следующий запрос:

`$mysqli->query("SELECT itemid FROM inventories AS a WHERE ownerid = 1 IN(SELECT itemid FROM items WHERE itemid = a.itemid)");`

Я пытаюсь провести все itemid из первого SELECT'а во второй SELECT, но проходит только первый itemid.

Хочу сделать что-то типа того, только одним запросом:

```
$q = $mysqli->query("SELECT itemid FROM inventories WHERE ownerid = 1");
        while($x = $q->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $mysqli->query("SELECT itemid FROM items WHERE itemid = ".$x['itemid']."");
        }
```

Comment: `ownerid = 1 IN` это вообще что?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим, что вы хотите получить все записи таблицы `items`, для которых есть соответствия в таблице `invetnories` с `ownerid = 1`

Или если смотреть с другой стороны, вы хотите получить все записи таблицы `inventories` для `ownerid = 1`, которые упоминаются в таблице `items`

Для этой цели обычно используют соединение таблиц, используя оператор `inner join`:

```
SELECT itemid
FROM invetnories as a
INNER JOIN items as i on (i.itemid = a.itemid)
WHERE a.ownerid = 1
```

или в другую сторону

```
SELECT itemid
FROM items as i
INNER JOIN inventories as a ON (a.itemid = i.itemid and a.ownerid = 1)
```

Либо с подзапросом

```
 SELECT itemid
 FROM items
 WHERE itemid IN (
      SELECT itemid FROM inventories WHERE ownerid = 1
 )
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все отлично работает.
Только есть ли влияние на производительность разных запросов?
В таблице просто будут тысячи записей, возможно даже десятки тысяч, поэтому хотелось бы знать какой выгодней использовать, чтобы быстрей вывести результат.

Comment: @Андрей создать индексы и анализировать планы выполнения запросов

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо почитать, как использовать `JOIN`.

Вот этот запрос покажет Вам все `itemid` из `items`, которые в `inventories` `ownerid=1`.

```
SELECT i.itemid FROM items i
JOIN inventories inv ON i.itemid=inv.itemid
WHERE inv.ownerid=1
```